# C multiple write access to a log file (linux env)

Tags: c, linux, syslog

I have a set of independent programs that I wrote in C. I would like all of them to write their log to the same file. Obviously comes the issue of control access. Two or more of them could end up writing simultaneously.

What is the most pragmatic way to achieve this?

I came across solutions using pthread/mutexes/etc but that sounds overkill implementation for something like that.

I am also looking at syslog but wonder if this is really for the purpose of what I need to do?

I feel that I need a daemon service taking the message and control when they are written. I wonder if that already exists.

Comment: "I feel that I need a daemon service taking the message and control when they are written. I wonder if that already exists."  Yeah, that's syslog.

Comment: This is kind of broad... Please specify additional constraints, and ideally provide some example code. `syslog` is one option, but it basically requires root access to configure logging.

Comment: If you open the log file in `O_APPEND` mode, and write each message with a single `write()` call, I think you're guaranteed to get what you want.

Comment: I am interested in your comment Steve as this could be a good option in the short run. Using the O_APPEND mode what happen if one tries to write when another is already writing. Will that block the writing process of the second? I'll dig and test this way.
This is to run on openwrt. syslog is called logd/logread there but I should be able to deal with that.

Comment: to avoid any problems with a 'race' condition, use the file lock/unlock features

Comment: @Noel Since we're talking about system calls here, it almost doesn't mean anything to ask "what happens if one tries to write when another is already writing".  If the OS kernel is single-threaded, individual system calls are essentially atomic.  And the definition of `O_APPEND` is that it turns each `write()` call into an atomic seek-to-end-then-write operation.  I'm not sure what would happen on a multiprocessor or otherwise multithreaded OS, but I'm pretty sure the OS kernel will take care of any exclusive locking for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am also looking at syslog but wonder if this is really for the purpose of what I need to do?

Yes

> I feel that I need a daemon service taking the message and control when they are written. I wonder if that already exists.

It exists in the Unix derivatives (including Linux) and is called... `syslogd`

More seriously, the `syslog` function is intended to pass a message to a `syslogd` daemon that will route it according to its configuration file. Most common uses include writing it down to a file or to the system console (specially for panic level messages when nobody can be sure whether the file system is still accessible). The syslog system may come with more features than what you are asking for, but it is an extremely robust and extensively tested piece of software. In addition, it is certainly already active on your system, so you should have a strong reason to roll your own instead of using it.

Comment: Worth explicitly pointing out that syslog is not just for system log messages.  Any application process can use it to write its own, application-specific log messages, which can be routed to its own, application-specific log files.

Answer (score 0):

You have two way :

First : Using something that already exist.
For the logging part, syslog (and syslog-ng) are well-know and well-used.

From that point, you can parametre syslog-ng to listen to an ip connection, and scan a dir for new file.

Your program can, when they will want to log, either connect to syslogng directly and send the log, and if the connection fail, write a new file in the directory that syslogng watch. 
That allow to not have the loss of the log is syslog-ng are interrupted for a reason or another.

Second : Develop something really similar to syslog-ng.
In that case, it's up to you.